# How do I fix this error when renaming a file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, file-rename

When I want to rename a file in the projectmap explorer in visual studio I get this Error message:
[image]
in English this means: "This operation cannot be completed. You are trying to move or rename an element in source control even though an element with that name already exists, the element is exclusively locked elsewhere, or the element path is invalid."

When I click on "Hilfe"(help) I am redirected to an invalid page.

I used to have a file that had the name I want to give this file. other names work. But I deleted this file from the project and I can't find it anywhere any more either.

I already tried the link and just rename the file like I do it every time.

Comment: Is it possible that you are working with Git or another version controller? It's possible that there is a file in another branch (not you rworking branch), that has a file in the same directory that has the same name you want it to give.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have meanwhile found a solution myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution myself:
I changed the current name in the vbproj file to the desired name then restarted visual studio. Then the document appeared again and I deleted it again. Then I inserted the content of the vbproj file that I had before the change again and restarted visual studio again.
Then I could rename the document without problems.